# How to set variable values from a ListView with Checkboxes?

Tags: java, android, listview

I created a listview with a custom adapter. The items have a checkbox next to them for each item in the array list/listview.

I basically want to set the values of the objects in the array list to true if they are clicked.

Looked in to `isChecked()` method But I'm having trouble understanding how it checks each checkbox for each item in the list when I only have 1 checkbox in my layout

I have a decent amount of java knowledge but trying to transfer the code I created there into a workable app has proven difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching your implementation would be helpful but here is the general idea:

Your ListView (hopefully RecyclerView, but not mandatory) contains logic for how to lay out particular items in the list of data that fuels it.  These reusable layouts and UI components are maintained in the ViewHolder pattern (which explains your single check box in the layout but you see 10 on the screen if your list has 10 items in it).  In each ViewHolder you have access to its respective CheckBox so you can setup a listener on the CheckBox to subscribe to its state changes (being checked or unchecked).  Inside the listener, you can call a function to update an element in your list.  ViewHolders have a nice variable internal to them called `adapterPosition` which, as you may have guessed, is the VH's position in the adapter (zero based).  This is usually super helpful since you can pass this variable around or reference your list directly with the index and it will match up to the correct item in your list.

Hope this helps, and I would be more than happy to assist you with the implementation if you provide some code samples!

Comment: I've created another post where I included my code, I would really appreciate it if you would take a look . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add one boolean parameter i.e. isSelected to model class that is used in adapter.
add listener to checkbox

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               //update isChecked value to model class of list at current position
               list.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
```

Then you can easily get checked items from data list of adapter.